# how can i resolve Hackerrank "terminated for timeout"?

Tags: c++, c++11

the question is to find no of reversible no.s below the following test cases and here reversible no.s means like `36 + 63 = 99` (contains both odd digit).
both `36` and `63` are reversible . and we have to find total reversible no.s 
below a number.

i have also declared functions as `inline` , but it is still giving timeout error . for test case#1  to test case#5

```
inline std::string IntToString ( int number )
    {
      std::ostringstream oss;
       oss<< number;
      return oss.str();
    }


inline int replacer (int n)

{
int r,R=0;

while(n!=0)
    {
       r=n%10 ;
    R=R*10+r ;
     n=n/10;
}

return R ;

}




int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   

int i,n,t,j,R,Q,L,k,d=0,M=0,D; 


cin>>t ; 

for(i=0;i<t;i++ )
    {
    M=0;
    cin>>n ;

    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        {


        if(j%10!=0)
       { d=0;
        R= replacer(j) ;

       Q=R+j ;
        std::string C = IntToString (Q);

        L=C.size() ;  


        for(k=0;k<L;k++)
           if(C[k]%2==0)
            d=1 ;
           if(d==0) 
          M++ ;
       }    
    }
    cout<<M<<endl ;
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add problem link.And may be you are using brute force which is giving timeout.Look for optimizations

Comment: FYI: Marking something `inline` does not give you a guarantee that it will be inlined. It's just a suggestion to the compiler.

Comment: Looking the code over, it appears to be a brute force solution. These almost always fail online judges because the Judge is looking for you to know or discover the trick needed to bring the time complexity down. I'd put this solution off to the side and do more research on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple generic answer would be "by making your code to do things quickly" i.e. by optimizing it.

Profiling tools may help you to point out "hot" part of code, but the resolution has to be done by you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a string in order to get a number's digits.
Transforming the int into string is a expensive operation given the fact that you use streams.
If you want to loop through a number's digits use this piece of code:

```
void loopThroughDigits(int n)
{
    while(n > 0)
    {
        int digit = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        //do something with digit
    }
}
```

Other than that, you should consider to store earlier result and start calculating from the previous 'checkpoint'. I don't know neither of memory limit or the biggest input, so I'm not sure that this is a reliable method.